# Ubuntu 20 lts freezes after launching some apps (chrome, settings)

Tags: 20.04, freeze

Recently upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 lts. And when I try to launch Chrome, Firefox...or even Settings - system freezes, I can only move mouse with frozen loading cursor. 
I still can launch terminal and some ubuntu apps (and even Slack). 
My laptop is Dell Inspiron 5570, Intel(R) Core i5-8250U @ 1.6GHz, 8gb RAM.

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       1.1Gi       4.8Gi     246Mi 1.8Gi       6.1Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi

sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.1.3
```

Don't know if this somehow connected, but just before freeze journalctl prints this error:

```
Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
```

Thx

Comment: What is "19 lts" you upgraded from?

Comment: Just to confirm, start with an `sudo apt upgrade -y`. When you launch an application, can you launch it from console to get output?

Comment: Found what appear to be related bugs - but for much older iterations of Ubuntu - [bug threads](https://ubuntu-bugs.narkive.com/pzJ6FgFe/bug-1486445-new-lots-of-zeitgeist-errors) without much of an answer - so just adding for reference.

Comment: @Pilot6, you are right, it wasn't lts, it was 19.10. Edited question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Don't know why, but I don't have any output with ```lspci```

Comment: What does `lspci` output without `grep`?

Comment: @DankyNanky, thank you. ```sudo apt upgrade -y``` seems to solve my problem. But now I can't power off properly, it just freezes again. But I think this is a minor problem.

Comment: @Pilot6, nothing. When I execute this command, it seems like terminal is waiting for somethig, I can't event stop it with Ctrl + C. Can only close this tab, that's all.

Comment: @DankyNanky. Unfortunately, the problem is still there. After reloading it freezes again during launching apps. Tried apt upgrade again, but without success. When I try to launch chrome from terminal, it doesn't show any output, freezes immediately.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues. In my case I installed 20.04 from scratch, after I used 16.04 for 4 years without mayor problems.

Comment: Can you confirm if `chromium-browser` or the official Google Chrome? What method did you install it with? `dpkg -i`, `apt install` or through Software Centre?

Comment: @DankyNanky Both chromium and official chrome (and even Opera, Firefox). Everything was installed via Software Centre.